# How does the Twilio outbound queue work for SMS messages?

Tags: sms, twilio

When sending SMS messages, I notice that outgoing messages tend to get delayed for 15-30 seconds in something called the "outbound queue" as noted on the Twilio logs screen.

For example:

[image: delayed message]

This is concerning because it leads to out-of-order delivery. I sent the above message, waited 5 seconds, then sent this one (same from, same recipient):

[image: second delayed message]

and the second one was delivered first. I understand the speed and success of delivering varies by carrier load, but I am expecting a FIFO process from Twilio's side.

Is the outbound queue owned entirely by Twilio, and is it affected by carrier delivery time, i.e., is there back pressure from slow carrier delivery? Is it a single queue shared by all API clients, or one per API client? What causes a message enqueued later to be dequeued earlier?

Comment: Twilio developer evangelist here. There can be many reasons this occurred. We're unable to tell you without identifying the messages themselves. Could you get in touch with [Twilio Support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) and send in the Message SIDs that correspond to the messages you've listed here and we can look into it.

Comment: @Ryan - did you ever figure out what was going on here? I'm experiencing the same

Comment: @joshblour: After going back and forth with Twilio Support, the root cause was described as such: "due to how we scale our infrastrature, traffic congestion can occur based on the overall traffic Twilio's processing." After escalating to Twilio Engineering, they were able to prioritize our specific Messaging Service to alleviate these delays. If you get in touch with Twilio Support, you may try to reference our ticket number: 797700. Good luck!